# Magento 2 : How to access the registry in controller defined in template fiile

Tags: magento2, registry

I have registered a variable in customer checkout view template `link.phtml` with code:

```
<?php 
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$reg_val = $registry->register('user_not_logged', '1');
?>
```

Again I wanted to access that registry through customer overridden controller `createPost.php`

```
 1. Defined protected variable :
   protected $_coreRegistry;
 2. passed in constructor 
  \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry; 
 3. Accessed coreRegistry object using :
   $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
 4. Inside execute() function
   $user_logged_registry = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('user_not_logged');
   var_dump($user_logged_registry);
```

This returns me NULL.

Can anybody explain me why I couldn't access the value of registered variable in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry is cleared after the server sends a response. Each new request starts with an empty registry. If you want to transfer data from one request to another you should use the session (`\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`) instead:

In block:

```
protected $session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session, 
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->session = $session;
    ...
}

public function getCustomersSession()
{
    return $this->session;
}
```

In template:

```
$block->getCustomersSession()->setData('user_not_logged', '1');
```

In controller:

```
protected $session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session, 
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->session = $session;
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    ...
    $isUserLoggedIn = $this->session->getData('user_not_logged');
    ...
}
```

Or using `objectManager` if you can not modify the `__construct` method:

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

Comment: Thanks. @Siarhey Uchukhlebau, I was unknown that registry is cleared after the server sends a response. I kept on looking the result with such circumstances. Your code and concept really worked for my work. You saved by time.

Comment: @sagarsapkota I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: How to access current user? like we use in m1 
Mage::registry('current_user'); same how can we use in m2?

Comment: @jafar You can use the `getCustomer()` method of the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` class, like this: `$this->session->getCustomer();`. This customer-instance will be obtained using a singleton, as like with a registry.